# Why aren't parameters binding to WebAPI app?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, get

I'm accessing a WebAPI resource like this:

```
localhost/myapp/api/values?ParamOne=123&ParamTwo=testing
```

In ValuesController, I have this:

```
public class MyParams {
  public int? ParamOne {get;set;}
  public string ParamTwo {get;set;}
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]MyParams someparams) {
  ...
}
```

When I try to access the resource, I get this error:

> HTTP Error 403.14 Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory

Here's the RouteConfig.cs, which is just the default:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new {controller="Home", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post the route config.

Comment: Just posted. I haven't changed the RouteConfig.

Comment: Is it an api controller or mvc controller? The route config looks like mvc config while the uri looks like api.

Comment: It should be api. This is a WebAPI app.

Comment: Look for the web api config inside the `WebApiConfig` file inside `App_Start` folder.

Comment: Found it and updated. Why does a WebAPI app have a RouteConfig?

Comment: Updated version isn't working. Do you have some idea how I can pass two parameters to a Get? I keep getting page not found.

Comment: The question does not show any update! Did I miss anything? Can you add your api route config from `WebApiConfig` & updated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WebAPI `Get` endpoint is expecting `someparams` as parameter **not** `ParamOne` and `ParamTwo`.

Changing your endpoint signature to the below should work with the given URL:

> localhost/myapp/api/values?ParamOne=123&ParamTwo=testing

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int? ParamOne, string ParamTwo)
```

**Updates**

The route configuration above in your question is for MVC controller not WebAPI Controller. See below for WebAPI route config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

In Global.asax.cs `Application_Start()` method, it is registered like so:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

NuGet packages required:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

One more thing, your controller must inherit from `ApiController` **not** `Controller`

Comment: That doesn't work either. What does the RouteConfig look like for this?